# WiFi configuration on Arch Linux ARM

Tags: archlinux, wifi

I have bought a Model A Pi, and I successfully configured it with a USB Wifi dongle on Raspbian. I recently prepared an SD card with the latest version of Arch Linux ARM and I am trying to get it set up with WiFi. I was trying to follow a Raspbian WiFi tutorial (thinking it could be the same as Arch Linux ARM) which said that there is a directory `/etc/network/` and you could set up WiFi from the `interface` file, but no directory `/etc/network/` exists. I heard about `netctl` but I have no Idea how to use it! I *do* have a supported USB WiFi dongle. Could someone please show me how I can setup WiFi on Arch Linux ARM? Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the wiki page? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Yes I have, but I had found it very confusing, thanks though

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The deprecated `netcfg` used `/etc/network.d/` to store profiles. The successor of `netcfg` is [`netctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl).

In order to setup a wireless network, install `netctl` using `sudo pacman -S netctl`. Next, you have to create a network profile. `/etc/netctl/examples/` contains some examples. Let's assume you want to setup a WPA2-PSK network. Simply copy over the example file and start editing:

```
/etc/netctl# install -m640 examples/wireless-wpa wireless-home
/etc/netctl# cat wireless-home
Description='A simple WPA encrypted wireless connection'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa

IP=dhcp

ESSID='MyNetwork'
# Prepend hexadecimal keys with \"
# If your key starts with ", write it as '""<key>"'
# See also: the section on special quoting rules in netctl.profile(5)
Key='WirelessKey'
# Uncomment this if your ssid is hidden
#Hidden=yes
```

Edit `MyNetwork` and `WirelessKey` as needed. Note the `640` permissions, you do not want to leak your wireless passphrase to the world!

Proceed with testing:

```
# netctl start wireless-home
```

If you do not get an error, you should be connected. Let's test this:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

To make this network start on boot:

```
# netctl enable wireless-home
```

Comment: I am getting an error that the job failed, what should I do?

Comment: Use `journalctl -af` to watch your logs. There may be multiple reasons, like incorrect password or SSID. Perhaps you have to change `wlan0` to something different due to a udev change, run `ifconfig` to determine the correct name for the wireless interface. If you have more bad luck, your USB dongle is not entirely supported by the driver.

Comment: @Lkensteyn Okay, thanks, I have a *supported* wifi dongle and it worked out of the box with raspbian. I'll try it out! Thanks!

Comment: Found this to be accurate, however, I ran into the following problems/solutions: "Profile <profile-name> does not exist or is not readable" - using a dash in the name of the profile causes some escape issues. had to take out the dash; "The interface of network profile <profile-name> is already up - had to take wlan0 down before starting my profile - `ip link wlan0 down`; `netctl start <profile-name>`

Comment: (errors above seen after running the command, failing, and then checking `journalctl -xn`)

Comment: I had to install `wpa_supplicant` in addition to the above

Comment: If you are working with things like rpi0 without a wired connection, you could do `sudo arch-chroot /tmp/a/root/` first.

Answer (score 7):

This didn't work for me at first.  After following the above instructions, I had to run

systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlan0

to make it work.  I found the answer at the [ArchLInux Arm Forum](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=5424)

Comment: Note that for this to work, you must disable all your netctl profiles first, e.g. `# netctl disable home-wifi`, and that the `wlan0` has to match your interface name, not your profile under `/etc/netctl/`. After that's done, this seems spot-on.